# How is this possible: Crystal filters for FM signals?

Tags: rf, analog, filter, signal, crystal

I am trying to make my own superhet reciever. I have achieved downconversion and I am trying to build a crystal filter that will only allow the crystal's resonant frequency through. In doing so, I had this thought.

My question lies in this:

- Assume an 11MHz quartz crystal with a very high Q factor, like 100,000.
- The 88-108MHz band has been downconverted to 8.8-28.8MHz (everything got shifted 79.2MHz down).
- A radio station at 90.2MHz got downconverted to 11MHz, the resonant frequency of our crystal. Frequency deviations limited to +-75kHz.

From my perspective, it seems that any frequency deviations from 11MHz would would be attenuated due to the high Q factor intrinsic to crystals. 11MHz/100,000 = 110Hz of deviation allowed. Our signal is frequency modulated with +- 75kHz so would this mean data loss?

Why do crystal filters work in FM receivers (In the US where 75kHz is the max deviation)? Does using multiple crystals with different resonant frequencies mean a wider bandwidth will be allowed through?

Thank you for your insight.

Comment: You need to design a ladder filter which contains many crystals at the same frequency and a handful of capacitors. However, ladder filters are generally narrow bandwidth. You can buy 10.7 MHz ceramic filters which are designed for FM broadcast receivers.

Comment: Either the crystal filters are used for NBFM (deviation of a few kHz max) or you are actually referring to ceramic filters, a whole different beast with 200+kHz BW. Please add a detailed reference to a broadcast FM receiver with a crystal filter - I've never seen such a thing! (And I designed an FM receiver for a high end audio company)

Comment: Fascinating point with the narrow-band FM. I had not considered this and saw many poorly labeled schematics, articles and videos which I assumed were broadcast FM . That makes much more sense. I suppose I will break out a spool of wire to finish my superhet then. @GrahamNye feel free to post your detailed comment as an answer.

Comment: @YousifAlniemi Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 11MHz/100,000 = 110Hz of deviation allowed. Our signal is frequency modulated with ± 75kHz so would this mean data loss?

Yes. Broadcast FM needs 200 kHz bandwidth. Traditionally wideband broadcast FM receivers would use LC filters (often as tuned inter-stage coupling transformers in the IF strip) to get adequate bandwidth before circuits moved to [ceramic filters](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceramic_resonator#Ceramic_filters), as noted by @qrk.

[image: Two amplifier stages linked with double-tuned transformer coupling]

[Source: Wikipedia - amplifier showing use of double-tuned inter-stage coupling transformers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-tuned_amplifier)

> Why do crystal filters work in FM receivers?

They don't, for broadcast use, as their bandwidth is too narrow. Narrowband FM, used for communication purposes, can use crystal ladder filters. An example design:

[image: A ladder crystal filter design.]

[Source: Wikipedia - Crystal_filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crystal_filter)

The above Wikipedia article links to a 1998 review of [the history of crystal filters](https://web.archive.org/web/20110909013316/http://ieee-uffc.org/main/history.asp?file=crystal).